# Initializing an array of arrays

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do the same thing than below but with less code.

```
    private $table = array(
        array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array()),
        array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array()),
        array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array()),
                               ...
        array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array())
    );
```

I know this is doable in C++, tho not sure if there is something similar in PHP.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
$a = array_fill( 0, 4, array_fill( 0, 5, array() ));
print_r( $a );
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: same here, im glad i asked ;)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a straight rectangle of known size, you might use nested loops:

```
$table = array();
for ($row = 0; $row < $rowCount; $row++)
{
  $thisRow = array ();
  for ($col = 0; $col < $colCount; $col++)
  {
    $thisRow[] = array ();
  }
  $table[] = $thisRow;
}
```

I know it's not exactly what you asked, but at least it'd be more resistant to change (like adding a column) than your current setup.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help, but like you said, it's not what i am looking for (i am actually running away from loops and "specific" assignments at each index...)